# Will stock amd cpu cooler work for different amd cpu

Tags: cpu-cooler, amd-cpu

I currently have an AMD sempron 140 processor in my computer. I plan to upgrade to a used AMD athlon ii x3 450. My question is can I use the stock cooler from the sempron 140 processor to cool the athlon ii x3 450 while still keeping a decent (with decent meaning a temperature where it won't overheat) temperature on it, or will I have to get a new cooler?

Comment: If it's the same socket, which I suspect it is, then the stock cooler is identical for both products.  I am just to lazy to research AMD sockets...

Comment: The sempron is am2+ and the athlon is am3

Comment: I would probably ask the vendor. Is that an option in your case?

Comment: No. In my case it isn't an option.